# StringBuffer behavior for NULL objects

Tags: java, null, stringbuilder

I am not able to understand the following behavior of StringBuilder when NULL objects are appended to an instance:

```
public class StringBufferTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nullOb = null;
        StringBuilder lsb = new StringBuilder();

        lsb.append("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Length is: " + lsb.length());// Prints 11. Correct

        lsb.setLength(0);
        System.out.println("Before assigning null" + lsb.length());    
        lsb.append(nullOb);
        System.out.println("Length now is:" + lsb.length()); // Prints 4. ???
    }

}
```

The last print statement does not print 0. Can anyone please help me understand the behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the StringBuffer API -

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append(java.lang.String)

> The characters of the String argument are appended, in order,
>   increasing the length of this sequence by the length of the argument.
>   If str is null, then the **four characters "null" are appended**.

This should explain the length as 4.

Comment: D*** shoud have read the documentation for append(String). Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder appends "null" when you give it a null reference. It eases debugging. If you want an empty string instead of "null", just test the reference before appending:

```
if (obj != null) {
    builder.append(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you set the length to 0; the "Before assigning null" prints 0.

Then you append `null`, which will appear in the buffer as the string `"null"`, which has length four.